# Json child access yahoo weather json in C#

Tags: c#, json, linq, yahoo

So I'm trying to get the weather from the Yahoo's weather Json, but the thing is I keep getting this error

> {"Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue."}

Right now I have no idea why is this happening. I checked the parenting a few times already, the spelling and all that.

```
    public String GetWeather() {
        StringBuilder theWebAddress = new StringBuilder();
        theWebAddress.Append("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?");
        theWebAddress.Append("q=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='"+ city + ", "+ state + "') and u='" + units +"'"));
        theWebAddress.Append("&format=json");
        theWebAddress.Append("&diagnostics=false");

        string results = "";

        using (WebClient wClient = new WebClient())
        {
            results = wClient.DownloadString(theWebAddress.ToString());
        }

        JObject dataObject = JObject.Parse(results);
        JArray jsonArray = (JArray)dataObject["query"]["results"]["channel"];        //This is the line that is generating the error.


        foreach (var woeid in jsonArray)
        {
            //stocheaza informatiile in variabile
            condition = woeid["item"]["condition"]["text"].ToString();
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(condition);
            return condition;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The link to the API is [here](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys). So as far as I see, there is problem with getting the child of query or results. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `query.results.channel` is not an array. Why don't you use `ToString()` to log `dataObject` and see what it is.

Comment: The code you have shown does not produce the error you have shown.  When I try it I get an `InvalidCastException` because `dataObject["query"]["results"]["channel"]` is not an array.  What information specifically are you trying to retrieve from the JSON?  Just the current condition text?

Comment: Weird... I get that error I was talking about. Yes, for now I want just the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing the code. Instead of using that code, I changed it with this

```
public string GetWeather(string info)
    {
        string results = "";

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            results = wc.DownloadString("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%27galati%2C%20ro%27)%20and%20u%3D%22c%22&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys");
        }

        dynamic jo = JObject.Parse(results);

        if (info == "cond")
        {
            var items = jo.query.results.channel.item.condition;
            condition = items.text;

            return condition;
        }
    }
```

Now it works as intended.